# improper integral limitation

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I have encountered difficulty when trying to calculate the limitation of an improper integral:
$$\lim_{\theta \to +\infty} \frac{1}{\theta ^2}\int_0^\theta \int_0^\theta \frac{\lambda}{t_2}dt_1dt_2$$
I don't know how to proceed with the improper integral $\int_0^\theta \frac{1}{t_2}dt_2$
Thank you so much!

Comment: It's a log, and it diverges.

Comment: $\lambda$ is constant so that you can take out of integral, now first term integral is also constant when integrate by $dt_1$

Comment: I actually come to $\lim_{\theta \to +\infty} \int_0^\theta \frac{dt_2}{t_2}$ is this limitation diverge? @Randall

Comment: Well, you have another problem in that the denominator makes no sense at 0.  You have an integral which is improper on both ends.

Comment: $\int_{\varepsilon}^\infty \frac{1}{t} \ dt$ diverges no matter what $\varepsilon > 0$ is.

Comment: can we take the derivative of this integral?

Comment: What would that even mean if it doesn't converge?

Comment: @Randall its real problem is $0$, not $\theta$, if the lower bound is $a>0$, then the limit is still meaningful.

Comment: @yahoo  I see what you are saying.  I forgot the $\frac{1}{\theta^2}$ out front.

Comment: @yaho so can we compute limitation in this case?

Comment: @Qing if the integral is $\int_a^\theta$ for some constant $a>0$, you you can compute the limitation. In the case $a=0$, you cannot.